# Is this construction grammatically correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was going through an essay and found this sentence:

> Contrary to many people beliefs, **many of those** BIO buyers, a recent study shows  that the nutrient content in the organically grown food isn’t very different from that of food conventionally grown.

After reading it a couple of times I've reasons to believe *many of those* points to the wrong word and it makes it harder to understand the meaning of the sentence. Is that the case?

Comment: The first problem is 'people beliefs'. Are these ones held by _people persons_? //  Ease of parsing is aided by amending to: 'Contrary to many people's beliefs, many of those people being BIO buyers, ...' or less starchily 'Contrary to the beliefs of many people – many of whom are BIO buyers – ...'.

Answer (score 1):

I think the quote was either written by someone whose native language is not English, or is simply not a good English writer. I think a more proper way to phrase it would be:

> Contrary to the beliefs of many people, many of *them* BIO buyers, a recent study shows....

I'm not crazy about reusing the word "many" in such close proximity in the two clauses, but most rephrasings to avoid it seem more verbose than necessary, so I stuck with it.